# Connectedness of $O(3)$ group manifold

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, topological-groups

A topological space is said to be [**connected**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) if it cannot be written as $X=X_1\cup X_2$, where $X_1,X_2$ are both open and $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset$. Otherwise, X is called **disconnected**.

Is it wrong to write $$O(3)=SO(3)\cup O(3)^{det=-1}$$ where $O(3)^{det=-1}$ are those elements of $O(3)$ with determinant $=-1$.

**EDIT :** 1. Should the disconnectedness be understood in terms of non-existence of a continuous path in the manifold that interpolates between these two sets?

2. Is there a way to show that, starting from identity, by a continuous change of group parameters, along a certain path in the manifold, I can reach all elements of $SO(3)$ but not those of $O(3)^{det=-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not wrong to write that, you're spot on the mark; therefore, your conclusion is right. Your example has an interesting generalisation beyond $O(3)$ and indeed beyone Lie groups as the following is true for all topological groups. For a topological group $\mathfrak{G}$, the "identity component"  $\mathfrak{G}_\mathrm{id}$ (*i.e.* the connected component of the group with the identity in it) is always:

1. Clopen (closed and open at once), therefore, by the connectedness argument, the whole group $\mathfrak{G}$ is connected if and only if $\mathfrak{G}_\mathrm{id}$ is a *proper* subset of $\mathfrak{G}$;
2. A normal subgroup of $\mathfrak{G}$, therefore the connected components of $\mathfrak{G}$ are precisely $\mathfrak{G}_\mathrm{id}$ and its cosets.

See the discussion [as Theorem 9.31 on my website here](http://www.wetsavannaanimals.net/the-lie-group-topology#TopologicalGroupNuclearGenerationTheorem) of this situation. Mine is a retelling of this slick little proof that I found a long time ago in

[Sagle, A. A. and Walde, R. E., “Introduction to Lie Groups and Lie Algebras“, Academic Press, New York, 1973. §3.3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0126145504)

This is widely known, BTW, but it's a little pearl of a proof, showing how powerful the connectedness argument is. I still enjoy reading it, just like I still like listening to "Walk Like an Egyptian" (for me, they come from about the same time of life!)

In your example, $\mathfrak{G}=O(3)$, the identity component is the smallest Lie group containing $\exp(\mathfrak{g})$, where $\mathfrak{g}=\operatorname{Lie}(\mathfrak{G}) = \mathfrak{so}(3)$; indeed, in this compact case, $\mathfrak{G}_\mathrm{id}=\exp(\mathfrak{g})$ is the whole connected component (in noncompact groups, *e.g.* $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, the identity component can be strictly bigger than $\exp(\mathfrak{g})$). $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is of course the Lie algebra of skew-symmetric, real $3\times 3$ matrices and, since $\det(\exp(H)) = \exp(\mathrm{tr}(H))=1$ for any such matrix $H$, we see that $SO(3)$ is the whole of  $\mathfrak{G}_\mathrm{id}$. It is a normal subgroup of $O(3)$, and the group of cosets is simply $O(3)/SO(3)\cong\{+1,\,-1\}\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$, which is another way of writing your decomposition.

Answer to edit 1: For manifolds, which are locally Euclidean (locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^N$) path connectedness and connectedness are the same notion. Moreover, path connectedness *always* implies connectedness (to prove this, assume otherwise and let $\alpha,\,\beta\in\mathbb{X}$ belong to separate connected components $\mathbb{U},\,\mathbb{U}^\sim$ linked by path $\sigma:[0,\,1]\to\mathbb{X}$ where $\mathbb{X}$ is the topological space in question and $\mathbb{X}=\mathbb{U}\bigcup\mathbb{U}^\sim$. By assumption (path connectedness), $\sigma$ is continuous when $[0,\,1]$ has its wonted topology. But $\mathbb{U},\,\mathbb{U}^\sim$ are disjoint, therefore so is $\mathbb{V}=\sigma([0,\,1])\bigcap\mathbb{X}$, so the inverse image $\sigma^{-1}(\mathbb{V})$, namely $[0,\,1]$, must also be the union of disjoint open sets, contradicting the known connectedness of $[0,\,1]$). However, not all connected topological spaces are path connected (look up the weird "topologist's Sine Curve" as a counterexample).

Answer to Edit 2. We have actually already done this above, because every matrix in $SO(3)$ can be written as a $\exp(H)$, where $H\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$, so you can take your path to be $\sigma:[0,\,1]\to SO(3);\;\sigma(\tau) = e^{\tau\,H}$. To prove that every $SO(3)$ matrix can be written in this was from first principles, simply witness that $\gamma\in SO(3)$ is *normal*, *i.e.* commutes with its Hermitian transpose and thus always has a diagonalisation with orthonormal eigenvectors, so $\exists U\ni\,\gamma=U\,\Lambda\,U^\dagger$, where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, none of which are nought ($SO(3)$ is a group). Thus, you can always define $\log\gamma = H = U\,\log\Lambda\,U^\dagger$, and you are done.

Note that this does not work for $O(3)$, because now $H$, even though definable as $H = \log \gamma$, $H$ now has diagonal elements if $\gamma\not\in SO(3)$, so $H\not\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$ and you can't find a path through $O(3)$'s charts, because $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is the Lie algebra of $O(3)$ as well.

Comment: The question I asked is wrong as pointed out by Red Act, I think. I will modify the question.

Comment: @Roopam I've modified my answer

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very easy mathematical proof that $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ i.e set of all $n\times n$ real orthogonal matrices is disconnected.

Standard Result 1: $ f: M_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(A)=\det A$ is continuous map.

Standard Result 2: $f:A\to B$ continuous map, if $A$ is connected or $X\subseteq A$ is connected then $f(A)$ is connected and also $f(X)$ is connected in $B$

Now consider $O(n,\mathbb{R})\subseteq M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and suppose it is connected set. so by $\det$ map from $M_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ image set must be connected in $\mathbb{R}$, but what is the image set under $\det$ map of $O(n,\mathbb{R})$? it is just $\{+1,-1\}$ which is a disconnected set so we get a contradiction.

Comment: +1 great, succinct answer. You probably already know this but *may* be worth emphasising: one needs to be wary of one thing: one either (1) needs to use the result that $O(n,\,\mathbb{R})\subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a topological embedding so that  $O(n,\,\mathbb{R})$ gets the relative topology (so that standard result 1 survives the restriction of its domain from $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ to $O(n,\,\mathbb{R})$ or (2) prove result 1 from first principles for $O(n,\,\mathbb{R})$. Not all matrix Lie groups are topological embeddings in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ (although $\det$ is still cts for the examples ...

Comment: ...I know of: e.g. the irrational slope one parameter subgroup of the torues). It's not a problem here, as there is only one possible topology a compact, simple Lie group like $O(n,\,\mathbb{R})$ can have and still be a Lie group: see [my account of a famous result be van der Waerden here](http://www.wetsavannaanimals.net/wordpress/how-unique-is-the-lie-group-structure-for-a-given-lie-group/) for example.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Thanks,thanks for the info :-)

Answer (score 0):

A topological space is connected if it *cannot* be written as $X=X_1\cup X_2$, where $X_1,X_2$ are both open and $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset$.  But you've just written $O(3)$ as a union, and

$$SO(3)\cap O(3)^{det=-1} =\emptyset\ ,$$

so $O(3)$ is not a connected topological space, due to that overlooked word "cannot" in the definition.

Comment: You are right. I had something else in mind. I will modify the post.